# form validation using jquery-validate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a problem and I don't what am i doing wrong since I follow several examples and none of them worked, I dont get any error, any signal, nothing, maybe someone can help me

Here's my code
HTML:

```
 <form id="contact" method="post" action="#">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name">NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="required input-xlarge" id="name-contact" name="name-contact" value="" placeholder="" minlength="2">
```

Jquery:

```
   $( "#contact" ).validate({
        rules: {
               "name-contact":{
                   required: true
               } 
       },
       messages: {
            "name-contact": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            }
       }

   });
```

this is the second time i tried to use this plug in because it looks very easy, it hasnt for me
Thanks in advance

Comment: [You've posted working code](http://jsfiddle.net/NP8sS).  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?  Did you remember to include the plugin?  It should come _after_ you included jQuery.

Comment: It is not working for me at all

Comment: Again I ask, are you getting any JavaScript errors?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code you've posted is working fine**, as you can see here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/NP8sS/**

---

Some notes, however only the first item could totally break things:

---

**1)**  Perhaps you forgot to include jQuery and/or jQuery Validate plugin.  Look at the left panel of the jsFiddle under "Frameworks" and "External Resources".  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

You should have two lines, in this order, where the `src` contains the correct URL to the location where you've placed those files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

---

**2)**  You've specified rules in two places.  You have the `required` rule inside `.validate()` and the `minlength` rule inside the `name-contact` element.  Maybe be more consistent and put them together instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/NP8sS/1/

```
rules: {
    "name-contact": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
     }
},
```

---

**3)** Your `for` attribute in your `<label>` contains an invalid `name`.  Should be:

```
<label for="name-contact">NAME</label>
```

---

**4)** You did not close your `<form>`.  You need to put a `</form>` tag at the end.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the answer, still I dont see any error message asking me for the name like in the jsfiddle file, dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: @paoloi, since I cannot see your page, how else can I help you?  Did you properly 'include' the scripts?  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?  Your OP is also missing the `</form>` tag.

Comment: @paoloi, again, how do I know those are good URL's?  You also have `type="text/javascript"` in one but not both.  And leaving off the `http:` does not work if your page is being tested locally.

Comment: thank you @Sparky I did place my include scripts correctly

I have no js errors

Comment: @paoloi, I don't know what to tell you, if your code matches the jsFiddle then obviously it should work.  It's impossible for me to see what little mistake you could have made, so everything here would be nothing but guessing.

Comment: here is the form complete: <form id="contact" method="post" action="#"><fieldset><label for="name_contact">NAME</label>
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name_contact" name="name_contact" value="" placeholder="" minlength="2">          
<button type="submit" value="" id="" name="send" class="pull-right lightblue btn-primary">SUBMIT</button></fieldset></form>  
and the js:
is $("#contact").validate({
        rules: {"name_contact": {required: true} },
        messages: { "name_contact": {required: "Please, enter a name"} } });

Comment: ty a lot my code is working now, fixed little errors with ur help...ur the best

Comment: @paoloi, The exact code you pasted into the comment above is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZA4qJ/

Comment: @paoloi, Ok, very glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Sparky is `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js` nessasary for your fiddle

Comment: @suhail,  no, it's not being used here.